# How do I remove decimals in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

Here is the code I'm using to prompt user to input wall's width in feet:

```
paintColors = {
  "red": 35,
  "blue": 25,
  "green": 23
}

wallHeight = float(input('Enter wall height (feet)): \n'))

wallWidth = float(input('Enter wall width (feet)): \n'))

areaOfWall = wallHeight * wallWidth

print ("Wall area: ", areaOfWall, " square feet")
```

I'm trying to remove the decimal from the code and there's no minimum or maximum.

Comment: Round to int you mean?

Comment: Give an example of your input for instance

Comment: `int(input('Enter wall height(feet)): \n'))` - both dimensions. int * int == int

Comment: Use `print("Wall area: " + round(areaOfWall, 0) + " square feet")`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the float value with `int` to get the value in integer, like this:

```
print("Wall area: ", int(areaOfWall), " square feet")
```

If you want to round off, use the `round()` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a decimal, you'd use the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#round) function, like this:

```
print(int(10.1))
```

Which would output:

```
10
```

To **round** a number (to the nearest whole number), you'd use the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#round) function, like this:

```
print(int(10.1))
print(int(10.8))
```

Which would output:

```
10
11
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this instead:

```
new_number = round(old_number)
```